# Extract pageviews from a all the pages of a wiki glossary?

Tags: python, php, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata

How do I go about extracting only page views (all time or maximum year-wise- not really interested in daily, monthly, etc) of all the subpages from a glossary page.

Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_areas_of_mathematics

I found this [tool](https://pageviews.toolforge.org/massviews). But it does category.

Is there a way in python or something which I can implement to GET pageviews for all the listed links on a page?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a simple way to do this because that article content is unstructured, unlike for a category.

You'll need to manually extract the page titles by parsing the article and then pass each of the titles to the API to get the pageviews. It is documented here: https://pageviews.toolforge.org/pageviews/url_structure/ you can pass multiple titles by separating them with | but there will be a limit to the number, so you will need to make multiple queries.